# Why am I locked out of the system?

Tags: wp-admin, login

I've installed a wordpress site for a client.
The site resides on mttv.co.il

For some reson I'm being locked out of the system most of the time with no error message displayed

The system takes the login & password and just redirecs me back to the login page.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: yes. when changing computer/browsers/etc it works once - which means it's probably cookie related, but erasing cookies dosn't help

Comment: cookies, check if they are set properly in the browser with witch it's not working.

Comment: maybe you use the firefox developer toolbar and have the checkmark on cookies?

Comment: @edelwater: good point, this can be a configuration issue in the browser as well.

Comment: @hakre: well maybe not lol since then maybe it would be not intermediate... i notice the wp-admin redirects maybe that has something todo with it.....

Comment: @edelwater: well actually this should always work on a vanilla wp install and cookies enabled in the browser. Just out of curiosity, what did you notice in wp-admin redirects?

Comment: also see: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/user-log-in-only-works-once

Comment: @edelwater (and @hakre and @hannit, hoping that you also see this): Maybe you should do the troubleshooting in [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6) and come back here once you have the solution. I have tried this once, and it is an improvement over the comment system if you need many back-and-forths to find the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If worpdress redirects you back to the login and password page (and not displaying any info that login/password was wrong), this is a sign that the login session is broken.

Most often this is related to cookies. Wordpress needs cookies for you to login. If cookies are not properly set or deleted later or are just mis-configured (there are some configuration constants available to control those, see in codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)).

You can tackle cookie issues down by using your browser and check which cookies are set or not set. Compare that with the information provided in codex to verify if that is your issue or not.

If cookies are properly created, transfered from server to browser and then back from the browser to the server on the next request, then this is not a cookie issue. Something else then prevents on your blog to keep the login session.

As the wordpress login session relies heavily con cookies, most often such issues are cookie related, because there is not much more to break. But sure, incompatible add-ons can break everything, so as well for that issue.

If you experience it only on one computer with one browser, give the computer a reboot. Probably you just had a hick-up somewhere and this solves stuff. Keep in mind that some firewalls block cookies or referrers. Blocking referrers can create problems to login: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page/ - But normally this creates a different behavior.